# VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter Driver Error

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I installed virtual box in my computer and it said device driver installation failed.
i tried to manually update the Virtual Box host only ethernet adapter but windows gives an error message saying "Access Denied"

My computer is running on Windows 7 and my virtual box version is 4.2.12

And When I try add host-only network via Virtual Box it gives an error saying "Failed to create host only network interface"

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the lefttop corner of VirtualBox manager.
- File-Preferences-Network-Host-only networks.
- Remove these that you have, if any. (acknowledge as root)
- Add a new one. (acknowledge as root)
- Check its existence in cmd - ipconfig
- Choose it using Host-only connection in Network of your virtual machine.

Maybe, you haven't administrator rights? Then you won't get acknowledgement window, and you really can't create it.